# how to solve mistake in url rewriting?

Tags: asp.net, url, iis, seo, rewriting

I'm using `Intelligencia.UrlRewriter` to rewrite url in web form asp.net.
I have a patch that rewrites from url.com/page.aspx?id=10 to url.com/page/10/

To rewrite I'm using the following code:

```
<rewriter>
<rewrite url="~/page/([0-9]+)/?$*[/]" to="~/Page.aspx?Id=$1"/>
```

This method is working well, but here is a mistake:
When I try this path :

```
 url.com/page/10/dada/asd/asda/da/sd/etc../
```

I will see contents of

```
url.com/page.aspx?id=10
```

And this is not good for seo.

**i want this:**
redirect from :

```
url.com/page/10/dada/asd/asda/da/sd/etc../
```

To

```
url.com/page/10/
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: ...and what exactly should be the rewrite target of the first URL?

Comment: i want redirect from url.com/page/10/dada/asd/asda/da/sd/etc../   TO   url.com/page/10/

Answer (score 0):

Use Routing for this purpose:

First of all, create Global.asax file.

Add following code to the heading part of the Global.asax:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>
```

Then change `Application_Start` method to the following:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

And add `RegisterRoutes` method:

```
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("", "Page/{page_id}", "~/Page.aspx");
}
```

In your *Page.aspx* use the next code to read the route value:

```
if (Page.RouteData.Values["page_id"] != null){
    //do anything what you need. For example, ShowPageValuesByPageID(Page.RouteData.Values["page_id"].ToString());
    //ShowPageValuesByPageID is your method
}
```

Comment: And then you will use the next to open any page: url.com/Page/10, url.com/Page/11, url.com/Page/100, and so on...